# Intersection of 2 Indicator Functions

Tags: probability, functions

Let $E$ and $F$ be events.

Let $I_E(\omega)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1, & \omega\in E, \\ 0, &\omega\in E^C. \end{array}\right.$

Show that $I_{E\cap F}(\omega)=I_EI_F$

I found the answer on this [Link](http://www.statlect.com/indica1.htm) as shown below

[image: Intersection of 2 indicator function]

However, I not satisfy with this answer, I hope I can show this question by using only plus, minus, multiply or divide, just like what I do to in this problem (but I not able to solve the intersection problem by using the similar method)

[image: Example]

Is it possible? Please show me. I appreciate your help. (I know my request is quite strange and hope you can understand what am I asking about)

Comment: Are you asking if $I_{E}^{c}(\omega)+I_{E}(\omega)=1$? If so, the answer is yes as it follows from the general property $I_{A}(\omega)+I_{B}(\omega)=I_{A\cup B}(\omega)$ for sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig I know your comment is old, but I need to note that your claim is clearly only correct for disjoint sets $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope that is what you search for
\begin{align}1_A(x)1_B(x)&=\begin{cases}
1& x\in A\\
0& x\in A^C
\end{cases}\begin{cases}
1& x\in B\\
0& x\in B^C
\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}
1& x\in A \cap x\in B\\
0\cdot 1& x\in A^C\cap B\\
1\cdot 0& x\in A \cap B^C\\
0\cdot 0& x\in A^C \cap B^C\\
\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}
1& x\in A \cap B\\
0& x\in \underbrace{(A^C\cap B)\cup(A \cap B^C )\cup(A^C \cap B^C)}_{=(A\cap B)^C}\\
\end{cases}\\&=1_{A\cap B}(x)\end{align}
Note that both aproaches only differ in notation

Comment: Simple and robust!!! Thank You!